# Webpack file-loader not working with html

Tags: webpack

I set file-loader to config file.
However, there is a problem that file-loader cannot read the image of the html file.
Do I need a different loader to read the image of the html file?
Or is there a problem with the setup?

```
{
  test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "file-loader",
      options: {
        outputPath: "/img/",
        name: "[name].[ext]"
      }
    },
    {
      loader: "image-webpack-loader",
      options: {
        bypassOnDebug: true, // webpack@1.x
        disable: true // webpack@2.x and newer
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself.
The html-loader setting was required to read the image file in HTML.
Adding this setting resolves the problem

```
{
  test: /\.html$/i,
  use: ["file-loader?name=[name].[ext]", "extract-loader", "html-loader"]
};
```